# Sencha Touch: Back button toggle visibility based on User Agent?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am new to sencha touch and I am trying to use the back button in my toolbar. I wish to toggle its visibility based on the User Agent detected. By default it is visible but if the user agent is detected as desktop I want to set `hidden : true`.

I cannot understand,

1. How to detect the UserAgent
2. How to toggle the visibility

Here is the code

```
myapp.views.SubSettings = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
 layout: 'fit',

 dockedItems: [{
 xtype: 'toolbar',
 items: [ {
   ui: 'back',
   id: 'backButton',
   text: 'Back',

   handler : function () {
    // this function should detect the User Agent and set visibility to false for back button
    }
   }
  ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detecting the user-agent there is the Ext.is class
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.is

Example to set the visibility of a back button on Android with the hidden property:

```
myapp.views.SubSettings = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    layout: 'fit',

    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            ui: 'back',
            id: 'backButton',
            text: 'Back',
            hidden: Ext.is.Android
        }]
    }];
```

Example if you want to check for the user-agent and set visibility inside the function

```
handler: function () {
    if(Ext.is.Android) {
        this.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great. I found out about Ext.is but didn't know I could use it `hidden: Ext.is.Phone` like this.